# Is there a way of checking that a result is the last (highest ID) in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that is used to display a blog post. At the start of the page, to obtain the data I'm using the following SQL:

```
SELECT posts.*, count(comments.post_id) as number_of_comments from posts left     join comments on (posts.post_id = comments.post_id) WHERE post_url LIKE '$post_url' group by posts.post_id
```

I have added a button at the end of the page to "read next post", which when pressed, finds the ID of the post currently being displayed then gets the next post from the db:

```
$(".readNext").click(function(){
    var result = "";
    var postID = "postID=" + $(".post").attr("id");
    $.get("/retrieveNextPost", postID, function (data) {
        //SomeFunction(data);
        window.location = '/blog/' + data;
    });
});

<?php
include('dbconnect.php');

if (isset($_GET['postID']))
{
    $post_id = $_GET['postID'];
}

$SQL = "SELECT posts.*, count(comments.post_id) as number_of_comments from posts left join comments on (posts.post_id = comments.post_id) WHERE posts.post_id > $post_id group by posts.post_id ORDER BY post_id ASC LIMIT 0, 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['post_url'];
?>
```

This is working great - until you get to the last (latest/highest ID) blog post. At which point - I'd like to remove the button from the page completely. Because it doesn't make sense to display it.

Is there a way of amending the SQL at the top of the page to mark some sort of Y/N flag that I can use to hide the button if true?

i.e. IF the current blog post record is the last/highest ID in the table, set flag to true.

Comment: I think you can do it by `SELECT *
FROM something
ORDER BY day_of_order;` and load posts by date.

Comment: So you have a loop to spit out the results. Attach a counter to the loop. While the counter is less than the number of items of the array, do something, then do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another left join to posts which contains the maximum post_id. If this matches (is not null) then you are at the highest post.

Off the top of my head:

```
SELECT posts.*,
    count(comments.post_id) as number_of_comments,
    -- if post_id matches then is highest
    case when maxPosts.post_id is not null then 1 else 0 end as IsLast
from posts
left join comments on (posts.post_id = comments.post_id)
left join (
    -- get max post_id and join on current post_id
    select post_id from posts order by post_id desc Limit 1
) maxPosts on post.post_id = maxPosts.post_id
WHERE post_url LIKE '$post_url' group by posts.post_id
```

Comment: This was perfect. Other suggestions about simply using order by/limit neglected to take into account my initial query is searching for a specific record. By implementing this SQL, I'm now able to do the following check in my PHP: if($row['IsLast'] != 1) and if this is true, I echo out the HTML code for my button. If false, I do nothing - and the button is never output on screen for the user. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use limit and descending in mysql query.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

set limit to 1 will allow you to get just 1 result. and using desc to sort the id from highest to lowest

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `MAX(posts.post_id)` to your select query and check if the current post is the last one.

```
SELECT 
    posts.*, MAX(posts.post_id) as last_post, 
    count(comments.post_id) as number_of_comments 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN comments on (posts.post_id = comments.post_id) 
WHERE post_url LIKE '$post_url' 
GROUP BY posts.post_id
```

then in the `php` return the output as `json`

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['post_id'] == $row['last_post']) $last = true;
else $last = false;

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( array(
        'url'=>$row['post_url'],
        'isLast' => $last
        )
);
```

Consume the `json` in the javascript part, by testing the if you have reached the last post and if true simply remove the button.

```
$(".readNext").click(function(){
    var result = "";
    var postID = "postID=" + $(".post").attr("id");
    $.get("/retrieveNextPost", postID, function (data) {
        if (data.isLast == true) $(this).remove();
        else window.location = '/blog/' + data.url;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of the above posts which allow you to grab the latest row using LIMIT & DESC in the query there is also other ways of doing this which simplify it.

For example:

PDO: You can access the lastInsertId(); function which returns the latest id of the row.

MySQLi: In your case i believe you are using MySQLi so you could use the mysqli_insert_id() function which works in a similar manner to the PDO function above.

Comment: These functions only act when the insert is carried out in the current connection session, and if used on a page where no insert has occurred they will return NULL. They are not very useful in this instance as the OP is not writing anything to the database.